# Save Lightning Web Component form by using wrapper class

Tags: lightning-web-components

My requirement is to create a LWC form by getting data from 4 different objects.
So I can't use LDS and need to use Wrapper class.

```
//just for an example to put mine requirement. 
Class Bikecreation {
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
 public static void save(Wrapperbike  bikeInfo) {
    //get the field value from the wrapper class and assign the data into the 
    //respective object and save it.
 }
  public class Wrapperbike { 
    public static String bikeName;
    public Static String bikeOwner;
    public Static String bikeContactId;
  }
}

//Want use wrapper class as an object
//Bike.html
<template>
    <lightning-card  title="Detail">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-input
            label="Bike Name"
            type="string"
            value={Wrapperbike.bikeName}
            class="string-input"
        ></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-input
            label="Bike Owner"
            type="string"
            value={Wrapperbike.bikeOwner}
            class="string-input"
        ></lightning-input>
    </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

//Bike.js
import saveBike from '@salesforce/apex/Bikecreation.save';

//get data from html fields
save(event) {
   
}
```

Comment: What's the issue within your code? And where you are stuck?

Comment: I stuck with getting LWC form field values in wrapper class and saving into salesforce database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did lots of research to find a solution. So I am posting a working solution. Created this solution in personal dev org. Now it seems very simple. Since LWC was new for me so it took time to solve this. This solution will help the beginner on LWC.

**createMultipleObjectForm.html**

```
<template>
     <lightning-card  title="Detail">

        <lightning-button label="Cancel" slot="actions" variant="natural"></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="Save" slot="actions" variant="brand" onclick={saveFormData}></lightning-button>

         <div class="slds-m-around_medium">                
            <lightning-input
                type="string"
                onchange={handleFirstName}
                class="string-input"
                label="First Name"
                value={firstName}
            ></lightning-input>            
        </div>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">                
            <lightning-input
                type="string"
                onchange={handleLastName}
                class="string-input"
                label="Last Name"
                value={lastName}
            ></lightning-input>            
        </div> 
     </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**createMultipleObjectForm.js**

```
import {LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';
import saveForm from '@salesforce/apex/createFormMultipleObject.save';

export default class CreateMultipleObjectForm extends LightningElement {
    firstName = 'Paul';
    lastName = 'Jacy';

    @track formData={
        firstName : this.firstName,
        lastName : this.lastName
    };

    handleFirstName(event) {
        //alert(event.target.value);
        this.formData.firstName =  event.target.value;
        console.log(this.formData.firstName);
    }
    handleLastName(event) {
        this.formData.lastName = event.target.value;
        console.log(this.formData.lastName);
    }
    saveFormData(event) {
        //alert('1');
        console.log('this.formData----'+JSON.stringify(this.formData));
        saveForm({moWrapper:this.formData}).then(res =>{ 
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

**CreateFormMultipleObject.cls**

```
public class createFormMultipleObject  {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String save(MOWrapper moWrapper) {
        System.debug('*****'+moWrapper.firstName);
        return 'Success';
    }

    public class MOWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled 
        public String firstName{get;set;}

        @AuraEnabled 
        public String lastName{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to edit your model to be `@AuraEnabled`, like so

```
 public class Wrapperbike { 
    @AuraEnabled public String bikeName { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public String bikeOwner { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public String bikeContactId { get; set; }
  }
```

Then, in JS you should be able to

```js
//Bike.js
import saveBike from '@salesforce/apex/Bikecreation.save';

//get data from html fields
save(event) {
  saveBike({ bikeInfo: { bikeName: 'Banana', bikeOwner: 'someIdHere', bikeContactId: 'SomeOtherId'} })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('yay!');
    });
}
```

I am guessing by the html you have already solved getting data out of LWC components?

Comment: Saving code is resolved my half problem. But getting data from HTML to JS is another issue. ex :   saveBike({ bikeInfo: { bikeName:Wrapperbike.bikeName})